# Symfony 5 - PhpUnit Panther : This version of ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version 80

Tags: php, symfony, selenium-chromedriver, phpunit

I am trying to use Panther with PhpUnit, it looks OK, but when I try to log a user like this

```php
        $client = static::createPantherClient();

        /** @var User $user */
        $user = $this->getSuperAdminAccount();

        $session = self::$container->get('session');

        $token = new UsernamePasswordToken($user, null, 'main', $user->getRoles());
        $session->set('_security_main', serialize($token));
        $session->save();

        $cookie = new Cookie($session->getName(), $session->getId());
        $client->getCookieJar()->set($cookie);
```

And I launch the test, I've the following error :

`Facebook\WebDriver\Exception\SessionNotCreatedException : session not created: This version of ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version 80`

And I've the latest chrome version :

[image]

But Panther does not allow the use of the chromeDriver associated with our version of Chrome. So I don't really see what I can do

Comment: Where you're running tests? Because I highly suspect that chrome versions you're seeing here, is not the same as the driver tries to use.

Comment: What do you mean "where do I run my tests?". Yes, the version of chromeDriver used by Panther does not match my version of chrome

Comment: I mean, if you're running in docker environment, or through CI, or locally, or whatever. BTW you should check what chrome instance is running with chromeDriver and see if it matches the requirements (and I expect it not to match, as error says)

Comment: Sorry I am not very advanced, I am training on Symfony. I'm using PhpStorm to run the tests, locally, I don't know if that answers your question. And I would like to see which instance of chrome is launched, but I don't see how

Answer (score 1):

This is my configuration:

```
composer show symfony/panther
```

```
name     : symfony/panther
descrip. : A browser testing and web scraping library for PHP and Symfony.
keywords : e2e, scraping, selenium, symfony, testing, webdriver
versions : * v0.7.1
```

Version 0.7.1 of symfony/panther has chromedriver 80.*, this is the problem.

There is an opened issue:
https://github.com/symfony/panther/issues/356

we need the updated version

EDIT:
Temporary workaround for dev environment:

```
CHROME_MAIN_VERSION=`google-chrome-stable --version | sed -E 's/(^Google Chrome |\.[0-9]+ )//g'`
CHROMEDRIVER_VERSION=`curl -s "https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/LATEST_RELEASE_$CHROME_MAIN_VERSION"`
curl "https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/${CHROMEDRIVER_VERSION}/chromedriver_linux64.zip" -O
unzip chromedriver_linux64.zip -d ./${projectpath}/vendor/symfony/panther/chromedriver-bin
mv ./${projectpath}/vendor/symfony/panther/chromedriver-bin/chromedriver ./${projectpath}/vendor/symfony/panther/chromedriver-bin/chromedriver_linux64
```

Comment: Have you try this @eronn?

Answer (score 1):

#### For someone who got the same error, this is what I did:

- Go to https://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads
- Select the driver compatible with your chrome version (If you are using Chrome version 88,  download [ChromeDriver 88.0.4324.27](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=88.0.4324.27/))
- Download your the driver for your OS (I downloaded it at the root of my project)

- Add `PANTHER_CHROME_DRIVER_BINARY=./chromedriver` in `.env.test`
- Run tests

If you are in Mac you may be noticed that `“chromedriver” cannot be opened because the developer cannot be verified`.
Simply enable it in your system preferences.